# perl script create same directory recursively as mentioned in input text file

Tags: perl

I am new in Perl and try to write perl script that take input from text file as a full directory name and create same directory with same file name ..

as input text is :

```
/vob/ccp/test/case/common_it/PTG_Scripts/ha/x86_64_obj/model_number.o
/vob/ccp/test/case/common_it/PTG_Scripts/ha/fru/x86_64_obj/fru_info.o
```

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
File::Path qw(make_path);
make_path($your_dir_path);
```